# Diferrent slider content from page to page

Tags: drupal-7, slideshow

Is there any slider module where I can change the content slider depend of the page.

By example : In the home page I have a slider with Picture1,picture2, picture3.

In the services page, I got, Picture4,picture5,picture 6

and so on.

I would like to specify for each pages, what will be the slider content.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best module in your use case will be Views Slideshow module.
https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

Create a view normally you will, add contextual filters, do whatever you like with it and fetch the contents dynamically based on pages, then use this views slideshow module to turn that view into a slideshow.

It has got an awesome set of features and is a very complete slideshow solution in itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is a nice module. Now I just need to find the way to add a kind of Fields in my content type listing my current basic page.